# Custom fonts (*.ttf)

Tags: android, fonts, textview

I have included a ttf file in my android assets folder.
I am using `day poster` as ttf.
But the problem is that this custom font is not being supported in some phones i.e.: it appears different in some phones.

The same issue is with `bebas.ttf`.

Please tell me how can I sort it out so that it appears the same in all mobile phones.

Output in Micromax(See text PETO)

[image: Output in Micromax(See text PETO)]

Output in Samsung(See text PETO)

[image: Output in Samsung mobile(See text PETO)]

Comment: Have you considered using [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)?

Comment: Version of both devices are same ?

Comment: I dont know about calligraphy @Addallah Alaraby

Comment: Add codes that you applied

Comment: No,@USKMobility,device version are not same,one is android 5.0 and other is android 6.0

Comment: USKMobility,it's working but the problem is above mentioned...There is no problem with the code

Comment: Are you using textview to display text?

Comment: I have create a custom textview USKMobility

Answer (score 1):

try this, add paint flags

```
setPaintFlags(getPaintFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Comment: Where should i use this

Comment: use in custom textview constructor or textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);